# Menu FireFox JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, menu, gui

Boa tarde, alguém poderia me fornecer uma ideia como criar esse menu JavaFX ?

[image: Menu Firefox JavaFX]

Comment: Só fazer o submenu ou tem que ter transição também? Se sim, forneça um exemplo do que tentou até o momento.

Comment: Ol[a, Renan. Até  o momento fiz o PopUPOver com o indicador. E dentro dele, quero colocar um menu com transição. Não sei se há MenuSkin ( classe ) algo do tipo para incluir novos nodes como exemplo acima. Obrigado !